# C++ basic coding issue

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a=0,b=0;
    cin>>a>>b>>endl;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;++i)
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to see the output is about the integers inclusive between a and b, but after entering two numbers, it shows no output..

Comment: This code doesn't compile - you don't need (and can't use) `endl` with `cin`.

Comment: aha,thx alot ty very much, I didn't even notice that..

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger - in a long run you will have to use it anyway to answer questions like the one you posted

Comment: You should also read [ask].

Comment: The code does not compile as-is, so "entering two numbers" is not possible. After fixing the syntax error (by removing `>>endl`), the code compiles and runs as expected. VTC as a typo that will not be of use in the future (because the text does not match the code).

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a=0,b=0;
    cin>>a>>b>>endl;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;++i)
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

First you can't use endl in cin
Second you wrote ++i inside your for loop which will increase value of by i means value of will become 1 from 0.
Therefore the condition will never be true as value of b is 0.

**THE CORRECT WAY**

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a=0,b=0;
    cin>>a>>b;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ifconfig what are you using? Turbo C?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
        cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I removed something as it wasn't true :P Silly me.

Also 'endl' doesn't work with cin :)

Comment: He can get all in one line.

Answer (score -1):

The code is wrong because you have already got a and b equal to 0,and after that you are taking a and b as inputs.
If you wanna take them as inputs you should write int a,b.  NOT int a=0,b=0

Comment: This is incorrect. Initializing `a` and `b` doesn't prevent them from being used as inputs.